# Voip, connect to asterisk servers over WAN with A580 base station

Tags: voip, asterisk

I have LAN infrastructure with asterisk and SIP phones(Gigaset A580) in it, I have done port forwarding on my public static ip address to my asterisk server in my LAN network, I also have trunk which I have rented so that phones from public PBX can call my SIP phones  and that part works.

Now I want to connect my SIP phone Gigaset A580 base station that comes with handset from other LAN, over internet, to my asterisk server.

Can you tell me what I need to accomplish that? 
I tried several configuration but with no success.

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've used Asterisk, and it's pretty tricky to configure. There is a lot that can go wrong. These suggestions assume that your Asterisk server and SIP handset is set up correctly and that you're able to connect to the Asterisk server from your internal LAN.

First of all, ensure that you have forwarded these ports to your Asterisk box, and that the firewall allows related traffic back out:

```
SIP = TCP & UDP Port 5060
RTP = UDP Ports 10000-20000
MGP = UDP Port 2727
```

Also ensure that Asterisk knows what its public facing IP is. Edit/create the file **/etc/asterisk/sip_nat.conf** substituting externip and localnet your own info.

```
nat=yes
externip=your.external.IP.address
localnet-192.168.2.0/255.255.255.0
```

Finally issue the command **sip reload**